# I cannot locate options in a dropdown while web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through all the options while scraping a website. The problem is that the options seem to be hidden within a javascript application, and I cannot locate the element that needs to be clicked to get the list of options.

I tried running the javascript application and select the right element but seems to be of no use.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json
import os


url = 'https://www.mfsa.com.mt/financial-services-register/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(1)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select1"))
select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select2"))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

test_soup = soup.find(id="select2-drop-mask")

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('select2-drop-mask').style.display='block';")
test1 = driver.find_element_by_id("select2-drop-mask")
test1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-drop-mask')

test1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-search')
print(test1.get_attribute('HTML'))
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('select2-results-1')
for li in test1:
    print(li.get_attribute('HTML'))
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='0']")
print(test1.get_attribute('innerHTML'))


test1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-hidden-accessible')
print(test1.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
test1.click()


options = [x for x in test1.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")]
for option in options:
    print(option.get_attribute('innerHTML'))


test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('select2-drop')
test1.click()


test1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-arrow')
print(test1.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
test1.click()


test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('select2-chosen-1')
print(test1)
test1.click()


test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('select2-drop-mask')
print(test1)
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('select2-results-2')
print(test1)
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen2_search')
print(test1)
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_select1')
print(test1)
test1.click()

test1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('select2-search')
print(test1)
test1.click()
```

The result I was expecting is a list of all options so I can loop through these and get a list of registered companies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a selection in the first dropdown for the second to have options. You need to click on both for options list. They are not `select` elements. They are list `li` elements within parent `ul`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.mfsa.com.mt/financial-services-register/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cn-accept-cookie').click()
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-chosen-1"))).click()
dropDown1Options =  WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-results-1 li")))
print(len(dropDown1Options))
dropDown1Options[2].click()
driver.find_element_by_id('s2id_autogen2_search').click() #OP needed  s2id_select2 instead in their attempt
dropDown2Options =  WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-results-2 li")))
print(len(dropDown2Options))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For selector 1 I had to add a time.sleep(2) before your "#select2-chosen-1" click. Do I have something wrong with my browser? Also, for the second selector I got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

Comment: I have no idea but you could try simply increasing the first wait to 10. Try  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#select2-chosen-1"))).click()   and tell me how that goes...

Comment: I didn't have either of these errors. Are you running the code as is - as per my example exactly? And by second selector are you referring to s2id_autogen2_search  ?

Comment: Also; why are you adding a # in front of the id? I only see this in my brower: <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-1">Company Service Providers</span>

Comment: I tried 10, but it still didn't work. For the second one I changed the id to s2id_select2 and worked

Comment: ok. well sounds like you got a version that works for you :-)

Comment: # is a css is an id selector